# Breaking for loop from within ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, break

I'm working on a school project and I'm developing a sort of game. In this game I require the user to login, and I'm facing some difficulties.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class User{
    int rank;
    String name;
    String pass;

User(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("  Login\n1.New user\n2.Old user");
    int in = s.nextInt();

    for(;;){
        if(in == 1){
            //create new user
        }else if(in == 2){
            JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame();
            loginFrame.setVisible(true);
            loginFrame.setLayout(null);
            loginFrame.setSize(120+14,180+35);

            JLabel enterName = new JLabel("Enter Username:");
            enterName.setBounds(10,10,100,20);

            JTextField nameField = new JTextField();
            nameField.setBounds(120,10,130,20);

            JLabel enterPass = new JLabel("Enter Password:");
            enterPass.setBounds(10,40,100,20);

            JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField();
            passField.setBounds(120,40,130,20);

            JButton hitEnter = new JButton("Login");
            hitEnter.setBounds(10,70,250,20);

            loginFrame.add(enterName);
            loginFrame.add(nameField);
            loginFrame.add(enterPass);
            loginFrame.add(passField);
            loginFrame.add(hitEnter);
            loginFrame.setSize(270+14,100+36);

            hitEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent enter){
                        name = nameField.getText();
                        pass = new String(passField.getText());

                        boolean validUser = checkUser(filename,name,pass);

                        if(validUser){
                            loginFrame.setVisible(false);
                            //some how break the for loop from here
                        }
                    }
                });

        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, I need to somehow exit the for loop from inside the actionlistener, but I'm not sure if there's any way to do this.

Please help me out!!!
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Instead of an infinite loop, why not use a while loop that checks the state of the login and exits once its successful?

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing event-driven GUI code and Scanner console code. Stay with either one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

- First and foremost, you're mixing Swing and console code in the same program and in a bad way. Understand that console (using a Scanner object based on System.in) is "linear" code, code where the programmer completely directs the direction of program flow, where we often use "blocking" code to get user input, code that completely blocks program flow until input has been entered, and this works well with your while loop. Swing GUI (and most GUI) code on the other hand is mostly non-linear event-driven code, code where the user has much greater control over what code is called when, code that mostly avoids blocking the flow of code (with the exception of modal dialogs).
- If you absolutely *must* combine the two, then you should **not** be using a JFrame, since displaying the JFrame will not pause the while loop, and it will loop endlessly, and not in a good way. Instead you would need to use the Swing version of blocking code, a *modal* dialog, either with a JDialog or a JOptionPane. These will pause the while loop, allowing for much cleaner and more linear input.
- And no matter which you use, none of the user interface code should be within the User class. This class should hold the state (fields) and behaviors (methods) of an individual user, but again should not include UI code. That belongs elsewhere; else you'll end up with a terrible mixture of spaghetti code that is hard to debug and enhance. So give your user its fields including name and rank, give it User methods that the main program can call when it wants the user to do something, but put your UI code in the main method.
- Gear your Swing GUI's towards creating JPanels, Then you could place the JPanel anywhere needed, making the code much more flexible. For example, if you did this, then you could place the JPanel into a JOptionPane, which means it would display as a *modal* dialog, blocking the while loop, exactly as you'd like.
- Minor quibble: avoid using String fields for passwords. This makes your program very easy to break into and is not a good habit to do.

So again if you absolutely had to mix Swing and console I'd do something like so:

First the User.java class. Again, keep it focused on user state and behaviors only:

```
public class User {
    private int rank;
    private String name;
    private char[] pass; // ***** Don't store password as a String
    // ?? other fields if needed

    public User(String name, char[] pass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // again, if this were a real-world program, you wouldn't make password accessible
    public char[] getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    // other User methods would go here

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [rank=" + rank + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

    // you'll want to override equals(Object o) and hashCode() here
}
```

---

You could then create a JPanel that is used to get user sign on information. I like using GridBagLayout when wanting to display this type of panel. For example:

```
// inports here....

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GetUserInfo extends JPanel {
    private static final Insets INSETS = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField(10);

    public GetUserInfo() {
        // gridbaglayout works well for your needs
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = INSETS;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(new JLabel("Name:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        add(nameField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(passField, gbc);
    }

    // allow classes to query this JPanel for the user name 
    public String getName() {
        return nameField.getText();
    }

    // and password data
    public char[] getPass() {
        return passField.getPassword();
    }

}
```

---

And then to combine the above in a console program, display this JPanel in a JOptionPane since this creates a *modal* dialog, one that blocks program flow until it is dealt with. You could use code like this:

```
    // user interface code can go here
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("  Login\n1.New user\n2.Old user: ");
    int in = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();
    User user = null;  // hold our user object
    boolean inputNotOK = true; // keep looping until this is false
    GetUserInfo getUserInfo = new GetUserInfo();  // our JPanel for getting user sign in information
    if (in == 1) {
        // code to get a new user
    } else if (in == 2) {
        // code to sign in existing user
        while (inputNotOK) {
            String title = "Get User Name and Password";
            int optionType = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;
            int msgType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
            int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, getUserInfo, title, optionType, msgType);
            if (value == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                // if the user presses "OK" on the dialog
                String name = getUserInfo.getName();
                char[] pass = getUserInfo.getPass();

                // validUser is a method that you have that checks if the user sign in is appropriate
                if (validUser(name, pass)) {
                    user = new User(name, pass);
                    System.out.println("new user: " + user);
                    inputNotOK = false;
                } else {
                    // show an error JOptionPane here to warn the user
                    // that their sign-on information was incorrect
                }
            }
        }
    }
    s.close();

// method that should check to see if user name and password are acceptable
private static boolean validUser(String name, char[] pass) {
    // TODO code to test if username and password are OK
    // TODO: change this to an actual test
    return true;
}
```

With code like this, if you later decide that you want to remove **all** console (Scanner) code, you can, since you've now got a JPanel that can be used in a desktop Swing GUI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm just a student, so I didn't know about all the stuff your'e talking about here, but thanks a lot again. Will definitely incorporate all your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go give that a shot

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class User{
    int rank;
    String name;
    String pass;
    //Added boolean up here
    boolean validUser;

    User(){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("  Login\n1.New user\n2.Old user");
        int in = s.nextInt();

        //Make sure it is set to false
        validUser = false;
        while(!validUser){
            if(in == 1){
                //create new user
            }else if(in == 2){
                JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame();
                loginFrame.setVisible(true);
                loginFrame.setLayout(null);
                loginFrame.setSize(120+14,180+35);

                JLabel enterName = new JLabel("Enter Username:");
                enterName.setBounds(10,10,100,20);

                JTextField nameField = new JTextField();
                nameField.setBounds(120,10,130,20);

                JLabel enterPass = new JLabel("Enter Password:");
                enterPass.setBounds(10,40,100,20);

                JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField();
                passField.setBounds(120,40,130,20);

                JButton hitEnter = new JButton("Login");
                hitEnter.setBounds(10,70,250,20);

                loginFrame.add(enterName);
                loginFrame.add(nameField);
                loginFrame.add(enterPass);
                loginFrame.add(passField);
                loginFrame.add(hitEnter);
                loginFrame.setSize(270+14,100+36);

                hitEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent enter){
                        name = nameField.getText();
                        pass = new String(passField.getText());

                        validUser = checkUser(filename,name,pass);

                        if(validUser){
                            loginFrame.setVisible(false);
                            //some how break the for loop from here
                        }
                    }
                });

            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            }
        }
    }
```